# I having 5 fields but i need to search by "username" in "search field". how we can do it in DJango Application

Tags: django, python-3.7

In my application there are fields like phone, username, Address, id. but i need only details of "username" field when i search it in search box. how we can do this . can anyone help me with DJango code

Comment: Can you provide more information like code or what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing search system? If you do, so use get_queryset(self). That will return username, that you search. And get_context_data()

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.filter(username__icontains=self.request.GET.get("q"))

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context["q"] = f'q={self.request.GET.get("q")}&'
    return context
```

Write down this one into your view, where is your search app.
in template, search form must have **name='q'**

Comment: this thing i need to do by using "Elastic Search"

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a model named `class Department(models.Model)` with 2 fields (name, description) in `models.py` like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Department(models.Model):
    DEPT_NAME = (
        ('Staff', 'Staff'),
        ('Manager', 'Manager'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=DEPT_NAME)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

At Django admin page you only want search result of `name` field.

In your `admin.py`, use the [**search_fields**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) attribute of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

@admin.register(Department)
class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    DEPT_NAME = (
        ('Staff', 'Staff'),
        ('Manager', 'Manager'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=DEPT_NAME)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    search_fields = ('id', 'name',) # <-- Choose any field you want Django search
```